# Google Apps: See all recently deleted users

Tags: google-workspace

So I need to recover a recently deleted user in a Google Apps account. I know how to do this and have done it a few times before.

The problem is that, just after the account was deleted, we deleted about six thousand other users. The "recently deleted users" list in the admin interface only shows the last one-hundred and there seems to be no way to search the list.

Is there a way to find the account I'm after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@kevtufc, you have a few options open to you:

1. Faster, more ghetto way

   1. If you don't remember the username, use the API explorer [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list#try-it), limiting your search to domain and showDeleted=True. This will return a list of recently deleted users for that domain. Note that you'll need to authorize, you can limit yourself to the read-only scope if desired.
   2. So with the username in hand (or from memory), go [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/undelete#try-it) and set userKey = the deleted user's primary email address. Execute the request and the user should be restored!
2. The slightly slower, more reliabile way

   1. Download and install Google Apps Manager by Dito. This tool is incredible. One of its great functions is [undeleting users](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-manager/wiki/GAM3DirectoryCommands#Undelete_a_User), with the syntax `gam undelete user <user email>`. Just [set up GAM](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-manager/wiki/GAM3GettingStarted) via the instructions and GAM away!